# Python Dictionary on Financial Literacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

In the given code I am working on financial planning. that involves a financial literate (fl) person and not a financial literate person (nfl).  I have to calculate their balance after 40 years of savings, loan payment, housing payment and plot it on a graph. it involves two dictionaries fl and nfl and am not sure how to input the dictionaries in the function because the last function "simulation" needs to call rest all the function and and if I input only in the last function it shows an error

```
import numpy as numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib 

fl = {"savings": 5000, "checking": 1000, "debt": 30100, "loan": 0, "yearsWithDebt": 0, "yearsRented": 0, "debtPaid": 0}
nfl = {"savings": 5000, "checking": 1000, "debt": 30100, "loan": 0, "yearsWithDebt": 0, "yearsRented": 0, "debtPaid": 0}
#nfl["savings"]=nfl["savings"]*1.01
#print(range(12))
house_var = False
house_var_1 = False
def savingsPlacement(person):
    """ 
    This function simulates the increasing interest on a person's savings account depending on whether
    they put it in a bank account or a mutual fund. 
    input: a dictionary representing fl or nfl
    output: an updated dictionary with the new savings amount after 1 year of it being in
    either the mutual fund of the bank account
    """ 
    nfl["savings"]=nfl["savings"]*1.01
    fl["savings"]=fl["savings"]*1.07

    return person
def debt(person):
    """ 
    This function simulates the amount of debt a person has left and the amount they
    paid after one year.
    input: a dictionary representing fl or nfl
    output: an updated dictionary. debt, savings, debtPaid, and yearsWithDebt
    are all changed each year if there is debt remaining.
    """
    if(nfl["debt"]>0):
        j=0
        for i in range(12):
            nfl["debt"]=nfl["debt"]-(0.03*nfl["debt"]+1)
            nfl["debtPaid"]=0.03*nfl["debt"]+1
        nfl["debt"]=1.2*nfl["debt"]
        j=j+1;
        nfl["yearsWithDebt"]=j

    if (fl["debt"]>0):
        k=0
        for i in range(12):
            fl["debt"]=fl["debt"]-(0.03*fl["debt"]+15)
            fl["debtPaid"]=0.03*fl["debt"]+15
        fl["debt"]=1.2*fl["debt"]
        k=k+1;
        fl["yearsWithDebt"]=k

    return person

def rent(person):
    """ 
    This function simulates the amount of money a person has left in their bank account
    after paying a year's worth of rent.
    input: a dictionary representing fl or nfl
    output: an updated dictionary with a checking account that has been lowered by the
    amount the person had to pay for rent that year.
    """
    nfl["checking"]=nfl["checking"]-850
    fl["checking"]=fl["checking"]-850

def house(person):
    """
    This function simulates the amount of money a person has left in their bank accont
    after paying monthly mortgage payments for a year.
    input: a dictionary representing fl or nfl
    output: an updated dictionary with a loan and checking account lowered by the
    mortgage payments made that year.
    """
    if house_var==True :
        for j in range(12):
            N = 360
            D = ((0.05 + 1) * N - 1) / (0.05 * (1 + 0.05) * N)
            P = 175000 / D
            nfl["checking"] = nfl["checking"] - P
            nfl["loan"] = (175000-0.05*175000) - P
    if house_var_1==True:
        for j in range(12):
            N = 360
            D = ((0.045 + 1) * N - 1) / (0.045 * (1 + 0.045) * N)
            P = 175000 / D
            fl["checking"] = fl["checking"] - P
            fl["loan"] = (175000-0.2*175000) - P

    return  person

def simulator(person):
    """ 
    This function simulates financial decisions over the course of 40 years.
    input: a dictionary representing fl or nfl
    output: a list of intergers representing the total sum of money that fl
    or nfl has each year. 
    """
    simulator()
    """for i in range(40):
        fl["wealth"]=fl["savings"]+fl["checking"]-fl["debt"]-fl["loan"]
        nfl["wealth"]=nfl["savings"]+nfl["checking"]-nfl["debt"]-nfl["loan"]
        fl["checking"]=fl["checking"]+0.3*29500
        fl["savings"]=fl["savings"]+0.2*29500
        nfl["checking"]=nfl["checking"]+0.3*29500
        nfl["savings"]=nfl["savings"]+0.2*29500
        savingsPlacement(person)
        debt(person)
        if(nfl["checking"]>0.05*175000):
            house_var=True
            house(person)
        if(fl["checking"]>0.2*175000):
            house_var_1=True
    return fl["wealth"],nfl["wealth"],person

"""
datafl = simulator(fl)
datanfl = simulator(nfl)

plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Wealth')
plt.title('Wealth of fl vs nfl Over 40 Years')
plt.plot(datafl, label='fl')
plt.plot(datanfl, label='nfl')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the error? Show exception traceback please.

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing, your functions all have signatures like this:

`def savingsPlacement(person):`

However, none of them use the parameter, `person`, that is passed in. Instead, they are directly referencing the `fl` and `nfl` variables.

This may perhaps be an assignment. If so, it would need rework. I would start by putting aside a copy of this version, and starting again. Pick one function, such as `savingsPlacement()`, and write only that, without any reference to the variable names fl or nfl at all. Instead, use only the variable `person`. Use only what you can know about a person at entry to the function. You may need to add another parameter for the other values hardcoded in some of your functions. Test the function by calling it with parameters from the Python command line. Only then proceed to the another function.

If this is not an assignment, you will find the resulting program more useful and general this way anyway.

Comment: yes, I realised it and changed the code with respect to the argument in the function and later edited few more lines which made the code run. Thank You for helping .